# Makefile:439: recipe for target 'mysql.o' failed

Tags: linux, gcc, operating-system

I'm not a Linux expert, but I'm studying for it and here is the "challenge": I'd like to port an ancient C application from Red Hat 9 to a newer version of Ubuntu / Debian (unfortunately, I don't have the original source code, just the binary). This application runs on a Virtual Machine using a very old version of MySQL (3.23.54a).

In a preliminary test, I tried to use a newer version of MySQL with minor modifications on the database: after fixing *"TYPE=MyISAM;"* by *"engine=MyISAM;"* and *"datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00'"* using *"CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"*... I got a *"Bad Handshake"* issue (not to mention the application required some files from the older version of MySQL in order to just open). So, first question: the only way is to install the older MySQL version?

Well... I tried to install this MySQL version from source using GCC 4.8.5 (installed by apt), solving a "Linuxthread issue" using

```
echo '/* Linuxthreads */' >> /usr/include/pthread.h
```

and *"/usr/bin/ld: errno: TLS definition in /lib/libc.so.6 section .tbss mismatches non-TLS reference in ..."* adding

```
#include <errno.h>
```

to the offended files. So, I got this:

```
Makefile:439: recipe for target 'mysql.o' failed
make[2]: *** [mysql.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/user/Downloads/mysql-3.23.54a/client'
Makefile:281: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/user/Downloads/mysql-3.23.54a'
Makefile:223: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

This isn't actually a "need", but just an exercise for my knowledge (this post has become an opportunity to improve my english skills as well).

Comment: If you don't have the source code, how do you plan to port it?

Comment: I have just the compiled file. In a first test, I copied the binary file to the new system (Ubuntu) at the same location as it was on the old system (Red Hat) and ran it with Qt 3 and later versions of GCC and MySQL (I had to copy some files from the older versions and make few adaptations on the database in order to import it). The program opened, but with bugs. Interesting. That's just an experiment for my knowledge. If I decrease the versions of MySQL and GCC, maybe I can run the application, can't I? What if I can use those ancient versions just for this application?

Comment: GCC doesn't have anything to do with anything if all you have is a binary.

Comment: Thanks! I was thinking about it, that's good. But... I need gcc to install mysql, right? Could I use a recent gcc version to install an old mysql?

Answer (score 2):

You should look at Virtual Machines. A virtual machine should help you create a new virtual environment running on top of your current environment. You can parametrize the virtual environment however you'd like without affecting your current one. A free virtual machine provider: https://www.virtualbox.org

All you need is the virtual machine image corresponding to the OS you want to reproduce. Eg here you want Red Hat 9 (from the official website) http://archive.download.redhat.com/pub/redhat/linux/9/en/iso/i386/

Comment: Thanks for your immediate response. Actually I have that VM running the application, but "the point of fun" isn't that.